# Angular6 Schema Form Dynamic Select

Tags: angular, angular-material, jsonschema

I'm using [Angular6 JSON Schema Form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular6-json-schema-form)

Where an html select element is described with json as below:

```
  {
"schema": {
  "type": "object",
  "title": "My Form",
  "properties": {
    "select1552420741389": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "select1552420741389"
  ]
},
"layout": [
  {
    "key": "select1552420741389",
    "type": "select",
    "multiple": false,
    "notitle": false,
    "title": "Select",
    "titleMap": [
      {
        "name": "Option 1",
        "value": "option1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Option 2",
        "value": "option2"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"data": {}
}
```

And I would like to have the option to dynamically load the titleMap via a custom callback function or specify a URL to call to get the titleMap data.

I've seen drop in libraries written in angular.js but I need a solution that works for Angular and Material.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I have had issues in the past with `angular-schema-form-dynamic-select` and dropped it in favor of a vanilla solution, which then I had to port into `angular6-json-schema-form` when we got the greenlight to migrate the project from AngularJS to Angular 7. While it does require quite a bit of elbow grease, it allows you to populate data or do whatever else you want in form initialization, with only vanilla schema forms.

In my context `| async` was not an option, because for reasons outside my control the data fetching returned a bluebird promise, which is not compatible with the async filter. If you do not have that limitation I would try and see if @Mic 's suggestion works first.

I created a helper for grabbing a promise's result (in my case, a HAL REST list endpoint) and transform it into a title map. In my case I always want the element's `name` or, failing that, its `description`, so that's what I went with:

```
  // returns a [{name: name, value: link}, ...] mapping of items for form
  // display based on a promise whose result is a list of entities
  private formify(promise) {
    return promise
        .then(result => result._embedded[Object.keys(result._embedded)[0]].map(element => ({
          name: element.name || element.description,
          value: element._links.self.href
        })))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Then another helper that creates the `onInit` callback:

```
  // returns an onInit callback for a simple select that is populated with
  // the list of entities supplied by the given promise
  private getStandardPromiseOnInit(formItem, promise) {
    return () => this.formify(promise)
        .then(function(result) {
          formItem.titleMap = result;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Then I add to my form item an `onInit` field:

```
  formItem.onInit = this.getStandardPromiseOnInit(formItem, callToRestService());
```

And after that processing my form definition object (it uses the AngularJS syntax as this was a port) will look something like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "type",
    "placeholder": "...",
    "type": "select",
    "onInit": <function....>
  },
  {
    "key": "equipment",
    "placeholder": "...",
    "type": "select",
    "onInit": <other function....>
  },
  ...
]
```

I have a service for obtaining form definitions that does this work.

Then when initializing my form component I recursively traverse the form declaration, looking for the onInit callbacks and executing them:

```
  form: any;
  ready: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.populateForm();
  }

  populateForm: Function = () => {
    let onInits = [];
    if (this.form) {
      // recursively traverse the form json
      let traverse = item => {
        if (item.items) {
          item.items.map(traverse);
        } else if (item.tabs) {
          item.tabs.map(traverse);
        }

        // call onInit callbacks
        if (item.onInit) {
          onInits.push(item.onInit());
        }
      };
      this.form.map(traverse);
    }

    Promise.all(onInits)
        .then(() => this.ready = true)
        .catch(error => {
          // error handling and message display
        });
  };
```

`this.ready` signals that all promises have been resolved, so the form can be rendered without having to force a redraw:

```
<json-schema-form *ngIf="ready"
    ...
    [form]="form" 
    ...
>
</json-schema-form>
```

Not as neat as a drop-in extension, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it myself, but it looks from the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular6-json-schema-form) that binding to `[layout]="yourJsonFormLayout"` attribute, with `yourJsonFormLayout` updated as you require would work.

You can also use an `| async` pipe to load the data from the URL you are querying, adjusting for the format as in

```
this.yourJsonFormLayout = http.get(...).pipe(map(...format your object...));
```